# Homebrew (unlike Macports) does not put programs ahead of system's

Tags: homebrew, macports, path

Macports inserts `/opt/local/bin/` ahead of `/usr/bin` in the path, and so if the same program exists in both folders, the Macports-installed one takes precedence.

I'm unclear on how Homebrew manages this issue. Taking a concrete example, say I run `brew install git`, I now have

```
> /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 2.14.2
> git --version
git version 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)
```

To use the more recent (git 2.14), it's tedious to use `/usr/local/bin/git`. Also, giving more priority to `/usr/local/bin` on my own may have undesirable side effects.

What's the standard way to run updated Homebrew programs when they collide with ones already on macOS? For `python` I've seen that Homebrew avoids collisions by requiring users to type either `python2` or `python3`. This is less clear for the case of `git`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General convention is in fact to put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin`.  This is doable via editing the `/etc/path` file or `sudo launchctl config user path "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`.  This will cause executables in `/usr/bin` to be shadowed by the ones in `/usr/local/bin`.  The [Homebrew FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html) suggests this.

Homebrew recipes will deliberately not link any programs into `/usr/local/bin` that could potentially cause system-wide conflicts (homebrew executables are actually installed in `/usr/local/Cellar` and symlinked to `/usr/local/bin`).  When you install a potentially conflict-causing package, homebrew will warn you about it, and say something to the effect of "We didn't automatically link this package.  If you really want to, you can run `brew link ..." Homebrew is generally pretty good about being respectful of existing system packages.

As an empirical anecdote, I have always shadowed `/usr/bin` with `/usr/local/bin` and have never run into any issues.  YMMV, of course.